# Shoud I use "did" or "does" in conjunction with "during this week"?

Tags: tense, do-support

Which one is right?

1. Did the student submit the paper during this week?
2. Does the student submit the paper during this week?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: Both are valid, but have different meanings. It depends what you want to say. More context is needed.

Comment: The 'during' is redundant in both cases.

Comment: @Neil W That depends on prior context. 'There was one particular week in May when all the papers submitted were mismarked....'

Answer (score 3):

Using "did" would mean that the week has now come to an end and you want to know if the student had submitted his paper within the course of the week. Using does is implying a future action that the student "will" at some time enter his paper during week, thus it would be better to say "Will the student enter his paper during the week?" instead of using does.

Answer (score 2):

Both statements are valid depending on the time when they are used:

1. First one is correct if it is being used at the end of "this week", so you are asking if the student had submitted the paper within that week.
2. Second one is correct if it is being used at the start of "this week", where you are asking if the student should/must submit the paper in this week.

Hope it helps.